# Reducing API Calls in React

Tags: reactjs

**Problem:**

I have a set of data that contains photos and userIDs.

For each photo I am rendering a `<Photo />` component.

Then when the `<Photo />` component renders, it is calling a function `getUserData` that makes an API call to get the user’s name from the userID in that photo object.

What I want to do is only grab each unique person’s name once. So that if the same userID is on multiple photos the application uses the previously cached value.

**My Attempt:**

I tried storing each value inside of a state object that I check against to see if the userID has already been fetched but because setState is async, as React does the initial render it loops over each photo object and returns the `<Photo />` which each make a request immediately for the same person since state hasn’t had a chance to update… which defeats the point.

Any suggestions here?

here is the function that gets called:

```
//createdBy is the user's ID
  getUserData = async (createdBy) => {
    if(!createdBy) return;
    if(Object.keys(this.state.users).indexOf(createdBy) === -1){
        //Get the user's info from the database and populate
        console.log('Getting new name');
        return this.getUserInfo(createdBy).then( contactInfo => {
            this.setState({
                users:{
                    ...this.state.users,
                    [createdBy]: contactInfo
                }
            });
            return contactInfo;  
        });
    }
    else{  //This user has already been fetched
        console.log('Reusing name');
        return Promise.resolve(this.state.users[createdBy])
    }
}
```

**EDIT: My Solution that Worked:**

I decided to not use `state` to keep track of the requests but only to keep track of the fetched data.

I updated my constructor() to be:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
       super(props);
    }

    //ADDED THIS LINE
    this.pendingUIDs = {};
}
```

Then I updated my function to check if the user id is already in the pending list which I can update during the same render.

I add the user's ID to the object. So that each function call can see if this user has been requested (even if the original call hasn't finished). Then when the original API call finishes, I update state, which causes a re-render and I can pass this user's info to `<Photo>` as a prop:

```
  <Photo userName={this.state.users[createdBy]} />
```

```
getUserData = async (createdBy) => {
    if(!createdBy) return;
    //******
    // NOW CHECKING this.pendingUIDs instead of this.state.users
    //******
    if(Object.keys(this.pendingUIDs).indexOf(createdBy) === -1){
        //******
        this.pendingUIDs[createdBy] = true; // <--- ADDED THIS TOO
        //******
        console.log('Getting new name');
        return this.getUserInfo(createdBy).then( contactInfo => {
            this.setState({
                users:{
                    ...this.state.users,
                    [createdBy]: contactInfo
                }
            });
            return contactInfo;  
        });
    }else{
        console.log('Reusing name');
        return Promise.resolve(this.state.users[createdBy])
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share you render method for better understanding of your situation?

Comment: The render method just loops over an object and returns a `<Photo userName={this.state.users[createdBy]} photoData={photo} />` for each photo.